# Confused About Systematic Sampling

Tags: sampling, systematic

So I was going through my notes and ended up extremely confused about a couple of things.

1.Suppose I have 20 employees and my population size is 200. I know that I need to take 200 and divide it by 20 giving me an interval of 10. I randomly selected the 35th person so the next person I need to select is the 44th person, and the next person after that is the 54th person, then the 64, 74, and so on until I get to 194. Now, if I add 10 to 194 I get 204 which means I've went over my population size. So the next person after the 194th person is the 14th person, followed by the 24th person, and finally the 35th person. Here's my question, how did they get 14? I plugged every possible way into my calculator but I still couldn't get 14.

2.Suppose we had a population of 200 and a sample size of 23. When we divide them together we get 8.6. I know that in this case my intervals will be every 8th person then every 9th person. What happens if we get 8.4? Do we pick every 7th and 8th person or do we just pick every 8th person?

Comment: The $194\to 14$ jump in your first question just looks like a mistake to me

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't a mistake. The end of the list was was reached and additional participants are still required so the count loops back to the beginning of the list hence why we went from 194 to 14. I just don't know how they worked that out.

Comment: But $194\to 4$ looks like the natural next participant, and 14 only after. Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: That's what I thought as well but I don't know why they have it down as 14. I've been getting different answers to this question so at this point I'm completely lost.